# C# AES-GCM and RSA Encryption using Sytem.Secuirty.Cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, aes-gcm

I am developing the post data request in c# and using AES GCM encryption and RSA encryption. As compared to the C# code with Node.js / Python for encryption, we found that C# AES GCM encryption does not have tag value in the method.
e.g How do I return below data in C# after encryption.

```
return {
key: aesKey,
cipher_text: encrypted,
tag,
iv
}
```

In Python and Node.js using JsEncrypt, forge.js.... and implementations are working fine. But, now developing the same client in the C#, do not find such libraries which I can use directly.

However, I found two classes in C# AesGcm and AesManaged for AES Encryption. But I think AesManages is only for AES not GCM encryption. Therefore, I am using AesGcm class in below example, but not sure.

The code executes the following steps:

1. Request client certificate from DSG.
2. Extract the public key from the certificate.
3. Encrypt PII with AES key.
4. Encrypt AES key with RSA public key.
5. Send wrapped key and PII payload to DSG tokenization.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string _ApiKey = "--- YOUR API KEY ----";
        string _SecretKey = " ---- YOUR SECRET KEY --------";
        string jsonPlainText = "<JSON TExT>";

        #region Certificate

        string certificate = GetCertificate();

        Certificate rawSigningCert = JsonConvert.DescrializeObject<Certificate>(certificate);
        var certBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawSigningCert.crt);

        // X509Certificate2
        var x509Certificate2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certBytes);
        byte[] publicKey = x509Certificate2.GetPublicKey();

        #endregion

        #region AES GCM Encryption

        byte[] aesGcmKey = new byte[16];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(aesGcmKey);

        byte[] nonce = new byte[12];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(nonce);

        byte[] tag = new byte[16];
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonPlainText);

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[dataToEncrypt.Length];

        using (AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(aesGcmKey))
        {
            aesGcm.Encrypt(nonce, dataToEncrypt, cipherText, tag);
        }

        string encryptedCipher = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);

        var keyString = Convert.ToBase64String(aesGcmKey);
        var iVString = Convert.ToBase64String(nonce);
        var tagString = Convert.ToBase64String(tag);

        string aesGcmEncryptionString = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", keyString, iVString, tagString);

        #endregion

        #region RSA Encryption

        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = publicKey;

        rsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

        byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = RSAEncrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aesGcmEncryptionString), RSAKeyInfo, false);

        var enc_key = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedSymmetricKey);
        var requestBodyObject = new { message = encryptedCipher, enckey = enc_key };

        string jsonRequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBodyObject);

        #endregion

        #region Calculating Message Signature
        Random random = new Random();
        int ClientRequestId = random.Next(0, 99999999);
        var time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        var rawSignature = _ApiKey + ClientRequestId + time + jsonRequestBody;
        HMACSHA256 hashObject = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_SecretKey));
        var signature = hashObject.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawSignature));
        var computedHmac = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);


        #endregion

        #region Make Request

        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient("< API URL>");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("contentType", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("clientRequestId", ClientRequestId.ToString());
            request.AddHeader("apiKey", _ApiKey);
            request.AddHeader("timestamp", time.Tostring);
            request.AddHeader("messageSignature", computedHmac);
            request.AddJsonBody(jsonRequestBody);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    static string GetCertificate()
    {
        string cer = string.Empty;
        // Code to get certicate .crt from the service.
        //"<GET CERTICATE HERE>";
        return cer;
    }

    static public byte[] RSAEncrpt(byte[] data, RSAParameters keyInfo, bool doOAEPPadding)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(keyInfo);
            encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
        }
        return encryptedData;
    }
}

class Certificate
{
    public string crt { get; set; }
}
```

How I can trace each steps as service is responding with incorrect message signature. Any way to verify and trace the above code steps?

Help!
Thanks in advance